# Is it an anti-pattern on React to search for children with a specific element type?

Tags: api, api-design, composition, reactjs, react

## Context

When designing the API of a React component, you may decide to receive props in a more semantical way. Here's a simple example

```
<Modal headerTitle="foo" />

vs

<Modal>
  <Header>Foo</Header>
</Modal
```

A more complex example would be this one, where we have a table and we need to set responsiveness:

```
const hideOn = { email: 'smDown'}
const data = [{ name: 'jonh', email: 'john@mail.com' }]
<Table hideOn={hideOn} data={data} />

vs

<Table>
  <Header>
    <HeaderCell>Name</HeaderCell>
    <HeaderCell hideOn="smDown">Email<HeaderCell>
  <Header>
  <Row>
    <Cell>John</Cell>
    <Cell>john@mail.com</Cell>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

In both scenarios, I'd strongly argue the second design brings more benefits (but not going to discuss that here).

## Pattern

Following the example above, in order to get the data for responsiveness of each of the tables `Cell`, `Table` need to run a `children.find(child => child.type === HeaderCell).props.hideOn` and pass the value to the `Cell` through `cloneElement`.

Another example would be making a component API strict so that only certain components can be passed. In this example, the hacked div won't be rendered at all:

```
<Table>
  <Header>
    <div style={{backgroundImage: './foo.png', top: 0, position: 'absolute' }}> 
      Hacked div. Programmer was lazy to figure how to put a background 
      image in the header.
  
      However, this hacked div won't get rendered
    </div>
  <Header>My Modal</Header>
  ...
</Table>
```

In this example, `Table` can run a `children.find(child => child.type ===` to find only valid children (`Header` and `Row`).

## Problem definition

What if we needed to do some decoration or just DRYing up the code, like the following:

```
<Table>
  <SharedHeaders />
  <Row>
    <Cell>John</Cell>
    <Cell>john@mail.com</Cell>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

At this point, we see 2 problems:

1. `Table` is no longer able to find the `hideOn` prop, because it doesn't have a `Header` within its children.
2. Assuming `Header` was one of `Table` valid children, `SharedHeader` is definitely not one of them.

This leaves me wondering whether the approach itself is fundamentally flawed, and I'm looking at the solution from the incorrect perspective.

I realize there are different options to solve the use case above (such as using the Context API), but I have other use cases where we work by finding a child with specific type, **so I want to focus the question specifically on that practice, and its take on composition**.

Is it an anti-pattern, when doing composition, for a component to search for a component with a specific type within its children in order to work?

Comment: There's no such thing as "correct."  Antipatterns are labelled as such because they are commonly used, even though their drawbacks exceed their benefits.  Is that the case here?

Comment: I believe so. If there was a way to have interfaces between react element types, then there would be no drawbacks, but right now there are more than benefits

Answer (score 1):

It’s not a big issue to use `cloneElement` on structured, nested data. It’s not surprising if `td` elements renders differently compared to `th`.
If you want to be explicit, you can always use the render props pattern. As an example, you can pass refs for calling imperative methods from the parent, or pass a callback to indicate that a child has changed. Something like this will suffice:

```
<Table rowCount={3} {...props}>
  {({onHeaderChange, onRowChangeCallbackList}) => (
    <Header onChange={onHeaderChange} />
    // render rows
  )}
</Table>
```